# Why the Campaign Tracking Parameters isn't working on Product Pages?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, redirect, product-urls

I have a situation where I send out email campaigns which link back to products. The link code is in the format:

```
?utm_campaign=EnewsNov&utm_medium=email&utm_source=HouseList&utm_term=editorial-link&utm_content=header
```

When I add the tracking link to my domain i.e:

http://www.domain.com/?utm_campaign=EnewsNov&utm_medium=email&utm_source=HouseList&utm_term=editorial-link&utm_content=header

It works fine. It also works fine for category pages.

For Product pages however the link is broken and I get an error like:

> This page isn’t working
>
> www.mydomain.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your
>   cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

If I however reduce the parameters to one i.e

http://www.domain.com/ANY_PRODUCT_URL/?utm_campaign=EnewsNov

It works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem with the campaigning. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In our case the issue was caused by the Creare SEO extension.**

**Class::function:**

> Creare_CreareSeoCore_Model_Observer::forceProductCanonical()

Simply setting the `creareseocore/defaultseo/forcecanonical` config field to No solved this issue.

[System] -> [Configuration] -> [CREARE SEO] -> [General Settings] -> [Enable Canonical Product Redirecting]

**This issue might also come from any other observer observing this event:**
`catalog_controller_product_view`

Disabling the module didn't prevent the observer from being executed. We had to comment out the entire function content to confirm it was the culprit.

Comment: Helped Me CREARE SEO was causing the issue. Thanks